# sort unique values on the same line

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

If I have a list of items like this in any text-area, I can use a bookmarklet to sort the unique values.

```
a
b
d
c
c
```

I click on the bookmarklet and the list is corrected to:

```
a
b
c
d
```

code:

```
javascript: (
  function() {
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('textarea')).map(function(b) {
      var a = document.createElement('div');
      var d = document.createElement('button');
      d.textContent = '↑';
      d.addEventListener('click', function(f) {
        f.preventDefault();
        b.value = Array.from(new Set(b.value.split('\n'))).sort().join('\n')
      });
      var c = document.createElement('button');
      c.textContent = '↓';
      c.addEventListener('click', function(f) {
        f.preventDefault();
        b.value = Array.from(new Set(b.value.split('\n'))).sort().reverse().join('\n')
      });
      a.appendChild(d);
      a.appendChild(c);
      b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b)
    })
  }
)();
```

But this does not work if all the items are on the same line like this...

```
a , b,d , c,c
```

Is it possible to modify the code to return the items like this...

```
a, b, c, d
```

---

I can do that in python. But I will like to know if it is possible using JavaScript bookmarklet.

```
myl = [i.strip() for i in text.split(',')]
myl.sort()
', '.join(set(myl))
```

Comment: `b.value = Array.from(new Set(b.value.split('\n'))).sort().join('\n')` - should be enough if you replace the split expression in there, and the join delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work better because since your input has blank spaces in it ,we have to use regex to split the string.

```
b = Array.from(
new Set(b.split(/[ ,]+/))).sort().reverse().join(',')
```

Comment: That was correct. Is it possible to remove descending option from the bookmarklet? I want the users to sort by ascending order only.

Comment: Yes ,just remove the reverse function.It would work fine

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
b.value = Array.from(
  new Set(b.value.split('\n'))).sort().reverse().join('\n')
```

You just need to change `'\n'` to `,`, like:

```
b.value = Array.from(
  new Set(b.value.split(','))).sort().reverse().join(',');

b.value.forEach(item => item.trim()); //to remove trailing whitespaces
```

Comment: That would be: [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).

Answer (score 0):

You could try lodash for this purpose,
As mentioned in other answers that you need to first change the words format
from :
a
b
d
c
c
to :
a,b,d,c,c

if changed

```
let x= // your values e.g a,b,d,c,c
//
let valuesArray=_.split(x,',')
uniqueFromArray=_.uniq(valuesArray)
```

if unchanged

```
let x= // your current input values 
//
let valuesArray=_.split(x,'\n')
uniqueFromArray=_.uniq(valuesArray)
```